# Minimum raise after flop

Tags: texas-hold-em

Game: Texas Holdem No Limit, blinds 5/10.

What is the minimum raise allowed **after the flop** in the following cases?

Case 1: player A first to act goes all in with 1 chip.

Case 2: player A first to act goes all in with 11 chips.

Case 3: player A first to act goes all in with 6 chips.

What is the minimum raise the next player can make?

Comment: I'm confused. The blinds are $5/$10, and another player has either $1 or $11 and goes all in.  You're asking what is the minimum raise a subsequent player can make?

Comment: Yes, my apologies if its confusing.

Comment: You would basically *never* play these stakes with $1 chips. Wouldn't it make more sense to think of them as $5 chips or just post your question in actual $ amounts?

Comment: It's play money. And is totally possible. Player A has 11 chips at the starting of the hand, calls the big blind and then after the flop goes all in for the remaining 1 chip.

Comment: I don't understand the meaning of such questions. Is this a hand that taken place anyway or is just another math exercise?

Comment: @vlzvl with all due respect, it doesn't matter what it is as long as it can happen, is a valid case. FYI i am coding a poker game so i need to know all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer by testing it on pokerstars. It's not the general rule, i know, but it's a solid solution.

Provided that the next player has enough chips for a minimum raise, that would be:

Case 1: 10 chips (1 big blind).

Case 2: 22 chips.

Case 3: 12 chips.

Cases 2 & 3 are nothing special, following the rule of adding the largest previous raise, so 11 + 11 and 6 + 6 respectively. For case 1, since the minimum raise would be under one big blind (1 + 1 = 2) the minimum raise is therefore increased to 1 big blind.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basic scenarios that get a little confusing when players are going all in. Scenario 1 is when the player goes all in for less then a full bet, your case 1 and case 3 are covered in this scenario. Scenario 2 is when a player goes all in making a raise that is less then the full raise this is your case 2.

The big problem is that the answer to these questions have a lot of variables involved. The way it would be done at a tournament often differs then the way it would be done in a cash game, but not always depending on where you are playing. The only right answer to this question is what you agree on at the time.

The important thing is that however it is commonly done is not particularly important, this is really a zero sum thing when the rulings are consistent for everyone. What is important at a card game is that whatever way it is done is known to the staff and players and always done the same way. There is really no particular best way to define this, just kind of depends what everybody is most comfortable with.

One should be aware that the short answer to the question of “what is the minimum raise allowed after the flop in the following questions” is that it depends completely on where you are playing, what shift you are playing on, who is dealing, and who is on the floor. You should expect different rulings from different dealers and floor people. You will find no consistency with rules here. Even people who read the rules have a bad time understanding the rules.

When you come across this type of situation you should just ask, and then when it comes up again ask again, good chance you will get a different answer.

Comment: As I wrote another answer I realized that there is nothing but localized answers to this question. It is one of those things that is just  not universally done the same way everywhere. So I deleted my first answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I think you are confused. There is no such thing as a legal 'minimum raise' - some gambling houses might insist on at least a big blind, but it is not a rule.

It actually a phrase meaning a player has made a 'minimum raise', i.e. they have raised but by possibly the smallest amount. They have not made any attempt at extravagance in betting to show off or bluff or intimidate, but just said 'okay i'm in'. Essentially a minimum raise is a 'limp', although limping refers to a player with a strong hand making a MR, which is tactics and depends on the environment and mood of the player in question.

Comment: I think this is missing the point. The OP is clearly asking for a specific number, not some philosophical conversation about extravagance.

Comment: He asks 'what is the MR ALLOWED ...', which in my Poker experience isn't true.